# getting rows from database with php - nothing returned

Tags: php, sql, database

So here is my php code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM WW_temp");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($numrows!=0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && $numOfPics >= 1){
        $ImageFilename = $row["image"];
        echo "$ImageFilename///";
    $numOfPics--;
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is ///////// (9 '/') when numOfPics is set to 3.
There is definitely some fields in the column 'image' in the database. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Try with `echo "{$ImageFilename}///";` ?

Comment: try to dump your row to see what's in it (`var_dump($row)`); this should help you (and us) figure out what's wrong. Maybe also add a sample of the `WW_temp` table so we can get a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You logic is squiffy. Currently your while condition is interpreted as:

```
$row = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && $numOfPics >= 1)
```

So `$row == true` while there are rows and `$numOfPics >= 1`.

Change it to:

```
while ( ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && $numOfPics >= 1 ){
```

and it should behave sane-ly.